# Celery and Python Client Server Architecture

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I need **help with celery and python**. I was able to configure celery after a lot of trouble. I got help from this link https://github.com/larsbutler/celery-examples I tried the example program and it ran fine as long as all the tasks.py, demo.py and celeryconfig.py were on the same folder. I transferred demo.py to some other folder and tried running it. It threw ImportError: Unable to import tasks module. I am using rabbitmq. I am not able to find more resources for python using celery.

I have two systems - Alice and Bravo. I want to access the function add residing in Alice from Bravo. ***I need help with the configuration of celery for this purpose. It is like client and server architecture.***

Comment: "I transferred demo.py to some other folder and tried running it."?  Did you change the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include this "other folder"?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the OP contacted me directly last Friday (duplicate post? :P) and I was able to help him resolve the issue. I think we can consider this question resolved.

As S. Lott mentioned, the proper solution was to add the other folder (containing `demo.py`) to PYTHONPATH.